# url-retrieve-synchronously on github doesn't return any response

Tags: url, ssl

Running the function

```
(url-retrieve-synchronously "https://api.github.com/users/lawlist/gists")
```

returns an empty buffer.  This only happens with github.

What could possibly be the cause?

Comment: It works fine from here using Emacs 26.2. If it doesn't work correctly, maybe it gives more details, check the buffer `*Messages*`. And you can also set the variable `url-debug` to `t` to enable logging.

Comment: If you are using emacs 26 you can try setting `gnutls-debug-level` to 1,2, or higher. See https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=34341#13 and http://emacs.1067599.n8.nabble.com/bug-32658-26-1-Cannot-connect-to-TLS-websites-tp464581p484081.html

Comment: Perhaps you have an issue similar to mine relating to an outdated version of openSSL:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/51285/url-retrieve-synchronously-how-to-retrieve-github-gist-list  One of the core maintainers (npostavs made a few comments that may be helpful underneath the question and/or answer).  I'm sure npostavs is right, but I just wanted to get it working with little fuss ... and I already had a newer version of openSSL on the computer (but not in the $PATH) and I just needed to adjust a couple of settings.

Comment: In addition to the suggestions above by Tobias and xuchunyang, you can cause Emacs to generate useful debugging messages by typing:  `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`.  If the issue is an outdated version of openSSL as described in the link to the thread in my previous comment hereinabove, then toggling general Emacs debugging should produce the same error report described in the question of said thread.

Comment: @lawlist i turned toggle-debug-on-error on, and the error is "connection broken by remote peer".

Comment: after upgrading to emacs 26.3, the problem now has gone.

Comment: @Tobias I think you meant `gnutls-log-level`.